# numpy.reshape() works in the Python terminal but not in a .py file

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to run a simple example of `numpy.reshape()`. It doesn't seem to work when called from a `.py` file, but when I try directly from the Python terminal it works perfectly.

I'm simply doing:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(6)
print a
a.reshape((3,2))
print a
```

It doesn't raise any error, but doesn't work either! Here's the output:

```
Lucass-MacBook-Pro:LSTM lucaslourenco$ python theClass.py
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

While in the terminal:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(6)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a.reshape((3,2))
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

Simple solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.reshape()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) returns a new object rather than modifying `a` in place, so you would need to assign the result back to `a`:

```
a = np.arange(6)
a = a.reshape((3, 2))
print(a)
```

Or to modify `a` in place you could assign directly to its `.shape` attribute:

```
a = np.arange(6)
a.shape = 3, 2
print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had a more complicated problem!